# Python enthought apptools with merging namespace

Tags: python-2.7, enthought

I am currently using python 2.7 with enthought from pythonxy package.

In my software, I need to use my own `user_manager` and other permissions tool. So I need to add external sources into `apptools.permissions`.

In apptools documentation, it said I need to develop another egg with namespace, `apptools.permissions.external`.

Therefore, I have developed a folder with three level:

- apptools,
- apptools.permissions,
- apptools.permissions.external.
- and setup.py.

In setup.py, I wrote:

```
# 3

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
      name = "apptools.permissions.external",
      author = "Airbus",
      version = '0.1' ,
      include_package_data = True, package_data={'': ['*.*']},
      packages = find_packages(),#exclude=["*.tests", "*.tests.*", "tests.*", "tests"]),
      test_suite = 'nose.collector',
      entry_points = """

      [envisage.plugins]
      apptools.permissions.external = apptools.permissions.external.permissions_plugin:ExternalPermissionsPlugin

      """,
      #install_requires = ['Aerocity==1.01'],
      zip_safe=True,
      namespace_packages = ['apptools', 
                            'apptools.permissions', 
                            'apptools.permissions.external',
                            ],
)
```

However, after I did `python setup.py develop`. I went to python and try to `import apptools.permissions.external`.

Python told me:

```
>>> import apptools.permissions.external
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named external
```

So it somehow cannot find this external egg. However, if I quickly changed the name of `apptools` to like `apptools_test` and related in folders and `setup.py`. I actually can import apptools_test.permissions.external.

So I think there is some problems when I merge namespace `apptools.permissions.external` to `apptools`. Python somehow gets confused.

Could someone help me with this case?

Answer (score 2):

`apptools.permissions` was architected a long time ago when it was `enthought.permissions` and `enthought` was a namespace package. We have long since stopped doing that and refactored most of ETS into separate packages (sadly, `apptools` is still something of a grab-bag). When we did that, it seems that no one noticed that it was (ab)using the namespace package like that. Sorry about that. We, uh, don't use it much ourselves. Take that for whatever cold comfort it brings you. :-)

The only places it does this kind of indirection is in `_*_default()` methods, so you *should* be able to just assign your own instances for these traits. I'm not really sure why the namespace extension mechanism was attempted at all.

Comment: Hi Robert,

Thanks very much for your reply. No worries.

This is related to our legancy software. It was designed using python 2.5 with enthought.permissions stuff. I am upgrading to python 2.7, and got this issue. 

Thanks very much for your suggestion. I had a look the __init__.py in apptools.permissions, it has no declare_namespace. I add it in and then everything is fine.

Perhaps, we need to find a better to namespace stuff it in the future. I would be happy if you would give me any suggestion. 

Thanks very much.